# Scroll has a jerking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When scrolling down the page the sticky menu is enabled and gets little jerky. What's the issue and how to get smooth animation.

```js
var elementPosition = $('.head_section').offset();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top + 150) {
    $('.head_section').fadeOut(100);
    $('.sticky-menu').fadeIn(100);
  } else {
    $('.head_section').fadeIn(100);
    $('.sticky-menu').fadeOut(100);
  }
});
```

```css
.home {
  height: 2000px;
}

.head_section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.sticky-menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
  <div class="head_section"></div>
  <div class="sticky-menu"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you used `jQuery` for the animation. So you need to remove the `transition` from your CSS. You can only use one, jQuery **OR** CSS, but not both in this case.

```js
var elementPosition = $('.head_section').offset();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top + 150) {
    $('.head_section').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.sticky-menu').fadeIn(1000);
  } else {
    $('.head_section').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.sticky-menu').fadeOut(1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.home {
  height: 2000px;
}

.head_section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.sticky-menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
  <div class="head_section"></div>
  <div class="sticky-menu"></div>
</div>
```